# Integration - finding range of function

Tags: integration

**Question:**

> Let $f:\big[\frac{1}{2},1\big] \to \text R$ be a positive, non-constant and differentiable function such that $f'(x)<2f(x)$ and $f\big(\frac{1}{2}\big) = 1$. Then find the interval in which: $$\int^2_{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx$$ lies in.

I have no idea how to attempt this problem. Please provide a hint so that I can begin the question.

Comment: You can try Gronwall's inequality. But I guess using FTC will be more straight forward.

Comment: @Svetoslav Not sure what FTC is?

Comment: I mean the fundamental theorem of calculus - Newton-Leibniz formula.

Comment: Not sure what that is... sorry. Would you mind posting a start to the question? @Svetoslav

Comment: $f(x)=\int\limits_{a}^{x}{f'(s)ds}$

Comment: @Svetoslav What is $a$ in that formula?

Comment: an arbitrary constant. In your case it can be for example $1/2$

Comment: Are you sure that $f$ is defined only in $[1/2,1]$ and not in $[1/2,2]$, because your integral is from $1/2$ to $2$ ?

Comment: @Svetoslav That's what it says in the question.. Let me give it a try with the formula you gave me.

Comment: @Svetoslav I get that the value of the function whose interval we need is equal to 1?

Comment: Then the question is not well posed. You can not integrate above $1$ because there the function is not defined at all. Maybe it is meant to estimate the integral from $1/2$ to $1$

Comment: @Svetoslav Might be.. It was a mutliple choice question.

Comment: Not well posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the integral is from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $1$. If something else, then the idea is the same.

**Hint**:
Because $f(s)$ is positive in $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ and $f'(s)<2f(s)$ then $\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}<2,\forall s\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$. Now we integrate this inequality from $1/2$ to $x$- some arbitrary number in $[1/2,1]$ and get
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}{\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}ds}<\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}{2ds}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\ln {f(x)}-\ln{f(\frac{1}{2})}<2(x-\frac{1}{2})=2x-1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ln{f(x)}<2x-1$$
$$f(x)<e^{2x-1}$$ 
Therefore, $$0<\int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}{f(x)dx}<\int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}{e^{2x-1}dx}=...$$ leave it for you to compute it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is positive, we see that the integral must also be positive. I am
assuming that $f$ is defined on the range of integration.

By letting $\phi(x) = e^{-2x}f(x)$, we get $\phi'(x) < 0$, and so
$\phi(x) = \phi({1 \over2}) + \phi'(\xi) (x-{1 \over 2}) < \phi({1 \over 2})$,
which gives $f(x) < e^{2 (x-{1 \over 2})}$ for $x > { 1\over 2}$. Integrating
shows that $I_f=\int_{1 \over 2} ^ 2 f(x) dx < {1 \over 2} (e^3-1)$.

If we choose $f(x) = e^{-\alpha(x -{1 \over 2})}$, with $\alpha < 2$ (and $\alpha \neq 0$), we see that $f$ satisfies the conditions and
$I_f = { 1\over \alpha} (e^{{3 \over 2} \alpha} -1 )$.
From this we see that the range of $I$ contains $(0, {1 \over 2} (e^3-1)) \setminus \{ {3 \over 2}\}$, the only spot in question is ${3 \over 2}$.

If we let $f(x) = 1+(x-{1 \over 2})({3 \over 2}-x)$, we can check that $f$ is positive, $f({1 \over 2}) = 1$ and $f'(x) < 2 f(x)$ on $[{1 \over 2}, 2]$. Then $I_f = {3 \over 2}$.

Hence the range of possible values of $I_f$ is given by $(0,{1 \over 2} (e^3-1))$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $f'(x) <2f(x)$ gives a hint to solve this problem. Now, you want to reach the integration of $f(x)$. So first of all we need to have a bound on $f(x)$.

Notice that the given equation can be written as:-
$$
\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} < 2.\\
\implies \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx < \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}2dx.\\
\implies \Big[ \ln(f(x))\Big]_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x} < 2\Big(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\Big).\\
\implies \ln(f(x)) < 2x-1.\\
\implies f(x) < e^{2x-1}.
$$
This might be a good enough for you to get to the answer. Ask any help if you find any doubt.